# How can I receive Email by using Windows Azure in my Website

Tags: php, html, azure-storage

Can I know about "Receive Email From Customer by using Windows Azure in my Website"?

Now I'm creating my company website.In this site,I will create "Contact Us" page.
This page will accept Email from my customer.
But this mail cannot not direct reach to my server by using WIndows Azure.

This page I will create with PHP language.

Can I create this function?

And how can I create this page? Do you know how to do this?

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want to do ?

Comment: I want to receive Email to my server by passing windows azure in my company website.Can I create this function or not?If I can create, I want to an example for this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Azure environment itself does not currently provide a SMTP relay or mail relay service. Steve Marx puts together a great sample application ( [available for download here](http://cdn.blog.smarx.com/files/EmailTheInternet_source.zip)) that does the

> following:
>
> It uses a third party service (SendGrid) to send email from inside
>   Windows Azure.
>
> It uses a worker role with an input endpoint to listen for SMTP
>   traffic on port 25.
>
> It uses a custom domain name on a CDN endpoint to cache blobs.

here’s the code that handles an incoming email:

```
// make a container, with public access to blobs
var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", null);
var container = account.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(id);
container.Create();
container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions() { PublicAccess=BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

// parse the message
var msg = new SharpMessage(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message.Data)),
    SharpDecodeOptions.AllowAttachments | SharpDecodeOptions.AllowHtml | SharpDecodeOptions.DecodeTnef);

// create a permalink-style name for the blob
var permalink = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(msg.Subject.ToLower(), @"[^a-z0-9]", "-"), "--+", "-").Trim('-');
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(permalink))
{
    // in case there's no subject
    permalink = "message";
}
var bodyBlob = container.GetBlobReference(permalink);
// set the CDN to cache the object for 2 hours
bodyBlob.Properties.CacheControl = "max-age=7200";

// replaces references to attachments with the URL of where we'll put them
msg.SetUrlBase(Utility.GetCdnUrlForUri(bodyBlob.Uri) + "/[Name]");

// save each attachment in a blob, setting the appropriate content type
foreach (SharpAttachment attachment in msg.Attachments)
{
    var blob = container.GetBlobReference(permalink + "/" + attachment.Name);
    blob.Properties.ContentType = attachment.MimeTopLevelMediaType + "/" + attachment.MimeMediaSubType;
    blob.Properties.CacheControl = "max-age=7200";
    attachment.Stream.Position = 0;
    blob.UploadFromStream(attachment.Stream);
}
// add the footer and save the body to the blob
SaveBody(msg, bodyBlob, message, container, permalink);
```